# How to display ganttchart with mysql database values in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, google-visualization

I want to make a ganttchart, where I can retrieve data from database using mysql.

Highcharts do no include ganttchart, so i tried google charts. I am able to  retrieve values from database and its can be seen in the page source, but not getting the output.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["gantt"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


        <?php 
         $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1") or die("could not connect");
         $query= "select * from view_chart";
         $qresult=mysqli_query($con,$query);

         $results = array();
         while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($qresult))
           {
             $results[] = $res;
           }

         $gan_data = array();
         foreach($results as $result)
           {
              $gan_data[] = ($result['Brands']);
              $gan_data1[] = ((int)$result['ratings']);
              $gan_data2[] = ((int)$result['bigbazar']);
           }
         $gan_data = json_encode($gan_data);
         $gan_data1 = json_encode($gan_data1);
         $gan_data2 = json_encode($gan_data2);
         mysqli_free_result($qresult);
      ?>


    function drawChart() {
     // var container = document.getElementById('gantt');
      //var chart =new google.visualization.GanttChart(container);
       alert('hello');
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?=$gan_data?>);

        data.addColumn( type: 'string', id: 'Brands' );
        data.addColumn( type: 'number', id: 'ratings' );
        data.addColumn( type: 'number', id: 'bigbazar' );

        data.addRows([
        <?php echo $gan_data; ?>,
        <?php echo $gan_data1; ?>, 
        <?php echo $gan_data2; ?>]);

        var options = {
        height: 275
      };


        var chart = new google.visualization.GanttChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data,options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know Google chart, but I'm quite convinced it supports JSON input. So it would probably be easier to json_encode a whole PHP array instead of printing single values. And it would also be less error like.